# Windows 7 user marked as admin but doesn't have the privileges

Tags: windows-7

Just got a new computer and am setting it up.  I setup one user during the install.  I've gone to computer -> manage -> Local Users and Groups and have verified that my user is in the admin group.

It looks like I'm missing a few things though.  In folder options there is no "advanced settings" section for me to turn on file extensions.

If I try to navigate to c:/users/username/Application Data it says Access Denied.  My old computer was part of a domain and I had admin rights.  On that computer I had access to the application data folder.

**EDIT**
I have two related questions:
How do I get access to my application data folder?
How do I get it so I can turn on file extensions under folder options?

I asked this as one question because I believe the root cause is the same, although I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: Does it happen to be part of a domain? Highly unlikely that is the case though. . .

Comment: This is not part of a domain.  My old computer was part of a domain and I could access the application data folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a junction to another location, and as you can see from the screenshot taken of a program called [NTFS Links](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html), it links `c:/users/username/Application Data` to `c:\users\username\appdata\roaming`. These faux folders are for backward compatibility, and have been protected by lack of default permissions for users so they are not used directly, or changed, even by administrators. Technically, as an administrator, you could still take ownership, and add permissions, but I do not recommend this.

You can also see that there are a LOT of them on this test Windows 7 virtual machine.

[image]

Comment: How would I take ownership of this?  I have to access an appdata's contents for an application I'm writing.  This worked fine on my old machine.

Comment: You should not take ownership of it. You should just write your app to use the new location (c:\users\username\appdata\roaming) as they are identical in use.

Comment: @Nate You should expand the environment variable `%APPDATA%` to find out where you should store your data, and not use any hardcoded paths.

Comment: @Nate.  You don't need to take ownership of it.  It is merely a hardlink to the real appdata.

Comment: i used the real appdata link and I am in.  thanks!

Comment: Great, thank you for marking the answer. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Application Data isn't real folder.  Hence the "Access Denied." Try double clicking Program Files.  Only admins are allowed in there. And it is a real folder, not a link.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Administrators group then You are an Admin and You have admin privileges.

In Vista/ Windows 7 some name folders remain but only as a inaccessible links.

Edit your post and write proper question, what do u need to do.